# Where does the cookie "_shopify_country" come from?

Tags: javascript, cookies, shopify

I want to redirect to the store associated to the country where the user is browsing from in my shopify site, based on [Slate](https://github.com/Shopify/slate).

Durring my research, I found a cookie named `_shopify_country` which the value set to the country of the user, but I'm afraid to use this cookie since it is [undocumented](https://www.google.com/search?q=shopify+_shopify_country).

I have two questions:

1. Where is that `_shopify_country` set?
2. How can I redirect to the site associated to that cookie using javascript? Should I *poll* cookies until it is set?

Answer (score 1):

I've had a little look at a few Shopify sites, and can't find the `_shopify_country` cookie. Seems is never set so I guess this is a custom modification to fetch it or possibly a deprecated function.

But if your goal is to determine what country the user is from, you can just submit an AJAX request to a GEOIP service. The API I tend to use for GEO lookups is  https://www.geojs.io which is a free non-authenticated GEO lookup,

Usually you would show a banner suggesting they change to their local site rather than redirecting youself though. For cases where they have a VPN/they are purchasing for someone abroad

Since AJAX requests are fired from the client, it will return his IP/Information from the example you can try these in your console.

Fetch IP

```js
fetch('https://canihazip.com/s')
    .then(response => response.text())
    .then(body => alert(body))
```

Fetch Country Code

```js
fetch('https://get.geojs.io/v1/ip/country')
    .then(response => response.text())
    .then(body => alert(body))
```

But back to the question, if you want to redirect based from the country code you could do something like so

```
fetch('https://get.geojs.io/v1/ip/country')
    .then(response => response.text())
    .then(country_code => {
        // Save as a cookie in case we want to use it later / in another page
        var date = new Date(); date.setMonth(date.getMonth()+1); date = date.toUTCString();
        document.cookie = `_visitor_country=${country_code}; expires=${date}; path=/`;

        var domain_and_tld = window.location.host.split('.').splice(-2).join('.');
        country_code = country_code.trim().toLowerCase();

        switch (country_code) {
            case 'gb':
                window.location.host = domain_and_tld;
                break;
            case 'us':
                window.location.host = `us.${domain_and_tld}`;
                break;
            case 'fr':
                window.location.host = `fr.${domain_and_tld}`;
                break;
        };
    })
    .catch(err => console.error(err));
```

The above code but as as ES5/with Support for older browsers

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('GET', 'https://get.geojs.io/v1/ip/country');
xhr.send();
xhr.onload = function() {
    if (xhr.status != 200)
        return console.error('Error '+xhr.status+': '+xhr.statusText);

    var country_code = xhr.response.trim().toLowerCase();

    // Save as a cookie, so we can reference this later if we want to
    var date = new Date(); date.setMonth(date.getMonth()+1); date = date.toUTCString();
    document.cookie = '_visitor_country='+country_code+'; expires='+date+'; path=/';

    var domain_and_tld = window.location.host.split('.').splice(-2).join('.');
    switch (country_code) {
        case 'gb':
            window.location.host = domain_and_tld;
            break;
        case 'us':
            window.location.host = 'us.'+domain_and_tld;
            break;
        case 'fr':
            window.location.host = 'fr.'+domain_and_tld;
            break;
    }
};

xhr.onerror = function() {
    console.error('Request failed');
};
```

Comment: This is helpful, thank you. https://vincerowatches.com/ is an example of shopify site including the `_shopify_country` cookie. My question was more about **when** should I do the redirect than **how**.